# user is not in the sudoers file

Tags: 18.04, sudo, virtualization, domain-server, visudo

Once configured my VM with Ubuntu 18.04 and joined to an AD domain, when trying to do sudo operation with my domain user, the error message is always:

```
"domainuser is not in the sudoers file. this incident will be reported."
```

I have an AD group with a domain user that can do sudo operations, and
I have also configured the group in visudo and in sssd.conf.
The VM is querying the domain successfully, and I can view it with 'kinit' or 'id' operation with my domain user.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/838/

Answer (score 0):

This may be counter-intuitive, but may help:

If you've been using, say, `usermod -aG sudo,adm DOMAIN\\user` or the same with `user@DOMAIN`, it doesn't seem to add them properly to sudoers.

Though there shouldn't be a local user with the same name, enter the name as if there were, like so:

```
usermod -aG sudo,adm user
```

Example: for domain `ACME` and user `admin`, in a `usermod` command, leave out the `ACME\\` or `@ACME` part entirely.

Literally just figured out this worked in the last few days.